# How to connect UITableViewCell button to perform UITableView functions?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an app which utilizes a tableView which contains a prototype cell. This prototype cell contains a few labels and a button (connected to that cell's UITableViewCell file).  If that's not clear, this is what I mean:

```
class ContactsCell: UITableViewCell { //this custom cell is used as the prototype cell for the tableView

    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var indexPathRowLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var replaceContactButtonUI: UIButton!

    @IBAction func replaceContactButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //THIS is the button in question
    }
```

The reason for this is because I'd like each cell in the tableView to have all of those labels (and the button), but with each row having different values in the labels. These values are handled by the `cellForRowAt` tableView function, via a system as follows:
Pressing a button (*not* the button in the cells I was talking about... a different button that is at the top of the VC, outside of the tableView) brings up the contact picker:

```
 func selectContact(){//allows user to bring up contactPicker

        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey]

        contactPicker.delegate = self

        contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count >= 0")

        contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count >= 1")

        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func selectContactsButton(_ sender: Any) {
        selectContact()
        //button brings up the picker to allow selection of contact
    }
```

Selecting one of the contacts updates an array which is used by the tableView to update the value of the labels:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    contactArray.append(contactProperty.contact)
    print(contactArray)// contactArray = [CNContact]()
    contactsTableView.reloadData()// reloads the value of the labels
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

These all work as intended. However, I run into a bit of an issue with the button that is *in* each cell. This button is intended to allow the replacement of a the `CNContact` in the tableView at the row of which the button was pressed... (ie if there are 4 rows, there are 4 "replace" buttons. Clicking the "replace" button of the third row replaces the `CNContact` at the 2nd index of the `contactArray`). This is where my issue is, though. Since the button, and its action, lives in the UITableViewCell's swift file, and *not* in the tableViewControllers, it doesn't have access to the `contactArray` to  remove and append, nor the picker functions to allow the selection of the new contact, nor the tableView itself to run `.reloadData()`. How do I 'give access' to the UITableViewCell's swift file to utilize things from the tableView controller that it is a part of/connected to?
**Note** Its possible that the entire premise of this question is wrong and that I should've actually placed the button's action elsewhere (*not* in the UITableViewCell's swift file). If this is the case, where should I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have all the information in your `ViewController`, I would suggest moving your `@IBAction` into your `ViewController` as well. If you are worried about referencing the correct cell, you can set the `tag` value of your `UIButton` in `cellForRow` method. Then in `@IBAction`, you can use that value to access the correct index in the array as well as the cell itself

Comment: But how do I connect the `@IBAction` of the button if all of the cell components are located in the `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: You can connect it in the storyboard just like any other button. Ctrl+click the button and drag it to the yellow circle at the top (UIViewController)

Comment: So I can use a prototype cell (with all the custom placement of UI elements) without putting their references in the `UITableViewCell` files? Sorry if that's a stupid question, but that's just the way I have always done it and haven't ever even thought to do it otherwise.

Comment: It is a good practice to have a separate file for Custom cells and referencing your `@IBOutlets` there. But when it comes to `@IBActions`, I tend to use them in the `ViewControllers` where they will be used and then just hook them up from storyboard. To put it another way, you can link an `@IBAction` of a `UIButton` (in a custom cell with an `@IBOutlet` linked to the CustomCell file) to an `@IBAction` method written in your `ViewController`

Comment: How do I do that? How do I link the `IBAction` from the CustomCell file to the `IBAction` in the VC? That would basically answer the question

Comment: And, with doing that linking, how do I pass the tag for the button's UI between the actions since they can't accept parameters?

Comment: If you're refering to updating label's value based on the button press, I would recommend against it. You should update your data source on button press and then update the labels through data source. If, however, you still want to update your labels by button press, you'll need to give the same tags to the labels as well

Comment: As for your previous question, you will not be defining your `@IBAction` in a Custom cell file but instead in your view controller's file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154191/discussion-between-alek-piasecki-and-malik).

Comment: @AlekPiasecki I have explained it in the chat. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

you can give selector to button in cellforrowatindexpath:

```
 cell.replaceContactButtonUI.tag = index.row
  cell.replaceContactButtonUI.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. 
selectContact(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

  func selectContact(sender:UIButton){}
```

From button tag you can find the cell index by sender.tag.